# how to retrieve rows from database selected from dropdown list in mvc 4

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

I want if the user select an Item from dropdown list all the ROWs from database that is included that item will be shown. any suggestion how to retrieve data with LINQ queries?

this is my model class.

```
public class Category
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }    // 

}
```

this is my another model where i populated the dropdown

```
public class FoodMenuItem
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public string Descripton { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    //to populate category table data into foodmenuitem table  as a NAVIGATION PROPERTY
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }  
    public Category Category { get; set; } //
}
```

This is my controller

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        //will contain the list of CategorytNames and it will bind this on the Create.
        //cshtml view as given below
        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "CategoryName");
        return View();
    }

public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        FoodMenuItem foodmenuitem = db.FoodMenuItems.Find(id);
        if (foodmenuitem == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }


        //checking what the selected value was using LINQ query and then using that value inside SelectList.
        //Now, DropDownList will look at the provided default selected value and displays it
        int selected = (from cat in db.FoodMenuItems
                           where cat.ID == id
                           select cat.CategoryID).First();
        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "CategoryName", selected);
        // ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "CategoryName", foodmenuitem.CategoryID);
        return View(foodmenuitem);
    }
```

Comment: You should be doing this with ajax. Handle the `.change()` event of the dropdownlist, pass the selected value to the controller and return a partial view based on the category, then update the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly right. Add following code in your view

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID ","--Select Category--")
```

Please try this. If it is not working then let me know I will find a new solution for this issue.